# how to manage different vertices in triangle

Tags: java, random

in the inner for loop I have `0<p1,p2,p3<3` and they are integer. I want this for loop to assign value from 0 till 3 to each parameter in demoMethod.i.e., once the for loop executes it will send parameter like (1,2,3) to demomethod and for the second time it will send parameter (2,3,0) to the demoMethod. also the order of these three numbers are not important and they must be different .it means that after two times that for loop executes it doesn't send parameter like (1,2,3) and (2,3,1). thanks

```
  public void Points(List<Point> pointList) {

    int n = pointList.size();

    if (n <= 2) {
        System.out.println("null");
    } else if (n == 3) {
        drawingLine();
    } else {

        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
          for(int j = 1;j<=(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/6;j++){
             demoMethod(p1,p2,p3);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but what is your problem ? I think you skipped some words ^^ but at first guess you are never init p1 p2 p3 they just appear out of no where in your code

Comment: I have just send a part of my code here! also I have edited my post :- )

Comment: do you want assing random variable or you want to calculate this p1 p2 and p3 values from n th element of the list. So, it's possible for you to draw the triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if I understand you correctly, you want to do something like this (?):

```
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j = 1;j<=(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/6;j++){
        int p1 =  j      % 4;
        int p2 = (j + 1) % 4;
        int p3 = (j + 2) % 4;
        demoMethod(p1,p2,p3);
    }
}
```